# Disable assert to custom field in form type step Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, assert

I have assert configured in my entity.
I created two forms types.
In the first, I have `name` and `url`. In the second I have `description`.

```
/*
*@Assert/NotBlank()
*/
$description;
```

When I try to submit the first form, it is not validated because the `$description` is blank.

But in the first form, not have the description field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are validation groups (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups and http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups).

Basically for your case you need to define two validation groups and set each one of them on your form types.

**YourEntity**

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"FirstForm"})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"FirstForm"})
 */
private $url;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"SecondForm"})
 */
private $description;
```

**FirstFormType**

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'FirstForm']
    ));
}
```

**SecondFormType**

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'SecondForm']
    ));
}
```